# NullPointerException in TurnBasedMatch when calling LeaveMatchResult in Android Sample SkeletonTbmp

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-play-services, multiplayer

I want to implement the turn-based multiplayer service. So, I first tried to run the sample (SkeletonTbmp). It works so far except when clicking on leave-Button. Then, a NullpointerException is thrown and I don't understand why.

```
public void onLeaveClicked(View view) {
    showSpinner();
    String nextParticipantId = getNextParticipantId();

    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.leaveMatchDuringTurn(mGoogleApiClient, mMatch.getMatchId(),
            nextParticipantId).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.LeaveMatchResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.LeaveMatchResult result) {
                    TurnBasedMatch match =  result.getMatch();
                    dismissSpinner();
                    //Status of result is OK here
                    if (!checkStatusCode(match, result.getStatus().getStatusCode())) {
                        return;
                    }
                    //match == null here but why???
                    isDoingTurn = (match.getTurnStatus() == TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_MY_TURN);
                    showWarning("Left", "You've left this match.");
                    //processResult(result);
                }
            });
    setViewVisibility();
}
```

The error message looks the following:

```js
03-02 15:40:29.445    5326-5326/com.tbmp.firstexample D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-02 15:40:29.445    5326-5326/com.tbmp.firstexample W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a8da0)
03-02 15:40:29.445    5326-5326/com.tbmp.firstexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tbmp.firstexample, PID: 5326
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.tbmp.firstexample.StartActivity$3.onResult(StartActivity.java:281)
            at com.tbmp.firstexample.StartActivity$3.onResult(StartActivity.java:273)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.deliverResultCallback(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can somebody explain me the error or do you need more informations?
The code is actually the same as the sample code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you error is at this line `com.tbmp.firstexample.StartActivity$3.onResult(StartActivity.java:281)`  whats at this line??

Comment: @Panther: The line is:  
`isDoingTurn = (match.getTurnStatus() == TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_MY_TURN);`